# How to write a unique value to a csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to writer unique values to a csv that already has a list of ints inside it.

Currently I have tried to loop through a range of possible numbers then check if those numbers are in the csv. It appears that the checking is not working properly.

```py
def generateUserCode():
    with open ('/MyLocation/user_codes.csv') as csvDataFile:
        userCodes = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        for x in range(0, 201):
            if x not in userCodes:
                return x

def writeUserCode(userCode):        
    with open ('/MyLocation/user_codes.csv', 'a') as csvDataFile:
        csvDataFile.write('\n' + str(userCode))

userCode = generateUserCode()
writeUserCode(userCode)
```

So it should print the first number not in the csv and add the number to the csv. However all it is doing is printing 0 and adding 0 to my csv every time it is run even if 0 is in the csv.

**Update:**

The csv looks something like this:

```
3
4
5
35
56
100
```

There are more values but it is generally the same with no repeats and values between 0 and 200

Comment: Could you provide us with the data or similar example data?

Comment: Probably you are checking for the int 0 in the `userCodes` when you have the string '0' in userCodes.  Try `if str(x) not in userCodes: ...`

Comment: @it's-yer-boy-chet Tried that but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

```
if x not in userCodes:
```

userCodes is not a list it is a csvReader object. Also, you should use

```
if str(x) not in line:
#use str(x) instead of x
```

This is the code that works for me:

```
import csv
def generateUserCode():
    with open ('file.csv') as csvDataFile:
        csvread = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        userCodes = []
        #print(userCodes)
        for line in csvread:
            try:
                userCodes.append(line[0]) # As long as the code is the first  
                                          # element in that line, it should work
            except:
                IndexError # Avoid blank lines
        print(userCodes)
        for x in range(0, 201):
            if str(x) not in userCodes:
                return x

def writeUserCode(userCode):
    with open ('file.csv', 'a') as csvDataFile:
        csvDataFile.write('\n' + str(userCode))

userCode = generateUserCode()
writeUserCode(userCode)
```

Comment: The other answers are great, too. I did not show how I figure out how to solve this. But I suggest you use more print command, which will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It’s tricky to answer without seeing the CSV, but when you read the CSV, all fields are strings. Therefor you need to convert either the `userCodes` to `int` or `x` to `string` for the comparison to work.

For example:

```
userCodes = [int(d[0]) for d in csv.reader(csvDataFile)]
for x in range(0, 201):
    if x not in userCodes:
        return x
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have tried the first fix with same results. I will try the second, What other info on csv do you need, I can add more.

Comment: Ah, looking at your CSV: you have a list of lists, each with one item. So you’re trying to compare a string to a list. I’ve updated my post accordingly, I hope it works now?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if a `str` is in an instance of `csv.reader`. This syntax doesn't work even with a normal file handle:

```py
with open('somefile.txt') as fh:
    x = fh.read()

 x
'Spatial Reference: 43006\nName: Jones Tract\n424564.620666, 4396443.55267\n425988.30892, 4395630.01652\n426169.09473, 4395426.63249\n426214.291182, 4395268.4449\n\nName: Lewis Tract\n427909.158152, 4393935.14955\n428587.104939, 4393731.76552\n428700.096071, 4393528.38148\n428745.292523, 4393347.59567\n\nName: Adams Tract\n424180.450819, 4393957.74778\n424361.236629, 4393709.16729\n424655.013571, 4393641.37261\n424858.397607, 4393776.96197\n'

# now check if 'e' is in fh

with open('somefile.txt') as fh:
    'e' in fh

False

'e' in x
True
```

Also, your csv file isn't really a csv file, so I'd just use a normal file handle and ignore the csv entirely.

The better approach may be to aggregate your codes in a `set` and check from there:

```py
def get_codes():
    with open('user_codes.csv') as fh:
        # return a set to test membership quickly
        return {line.strip() for line in fh}

codes = get_codes()

def add_code(code):
    if code not in codes:
        codes.add(code)
        with open('user_codes.csv', 'a') as fh:
            fh.write(code)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Code already exists")
        # or do something else

add_code(88)
add_code(88)
# ValueError
```

To generate a user code automatically, since you are using a `range`, this becomes relatively easy:

```py
def generate_user_code():
    try:
        # this returns the first number not in codes
        return next(i for i in range(201) if i not in codes)
    except StopIteration:
        # you've exhausted your range, nothing is left
        raise ValueError("No unique codes available")

# and your write method can be changed to
def add_code(code):
    with open('user_codes.csv', 'a') as fh:
        codes.add(code)
        fh.write(code)


codes = get_codes()
user_code = generate_user_code()
add_code(user_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating userCodes shows each item is a list of strings:

```
 for x in userCodes:
     print(x)
```

returns:

```
 ['3']
 ['4']
 ['5']
 ['35']
 ['56']
 ['100']
```

So there are a lot of possible fixes, one would be:

```
def generateUserCode():
    with open ('/MyLocation/user_codes.csv') as csvDataFile:
        userCodes = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        userCodes = [int(item[0]) for item in userCodes]
        for x in range(0, 201):
            if x not in userCodes:
                return x
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to do this:

```
....
userCodes = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
uc = []
for y in userCodes:
    uc += y
for x in range(0, 201):
    if str(x) not in uc:
        return x
....
```